# How do I filter a typescript array with items in another array

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have 2 arrays:

```
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "All",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "APR",
  },
 {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "TER",
  }]
```

The second array is `["APR", "TER"]`

I want to filter the first array with the second that is the output should be

```
  [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "APR",
  },{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "TER",
  }]
```

Trying this with filter function - is that possible?

Thanks
Anand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty standard use of the filter method. Just give it the right condition to check, and you're good to go:

```js
const myArray = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "All",
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "APR",
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "TER",
}];

const otherArray = [
  "APR",
  "TER",
];

const filtered = myArray.filter(x => otherArray.includes(x.name));

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter your array with the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```
const items =  [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "All",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "APR",
  },
 {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "TER",
  }]

const filterValues = ["APR", "TER"]

const filtered = items.filter(item => filterValues.indexOf(item.name) > -1)
```

Comment: @anand I update the code after you edited your question